# Design DAO methods and nested entities

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I am working on project that use plain JDBC to connect with database. I am trying to make it more maintenance friendly and refactoring some structures and queries that fetch the data.

I faced some design problem that I can't figure out.

Database tables (simplified):

```
Person
int id,
varchar firstName,
varchar lastName,
date dateOfBirth,

PersonAddress
int id,
int personId,
int cityId,
int countryId,

PersonBankAccount
int id,
int personId,
varchar accountIBAN
```

Every person can have multiple addreses and multiple bank accounts (1..n). The most reasonable java entity for Person would be then:

```
class Person {
    Integer id;
    List<PersonAddress> addreses;
    List<PersonBankAccount> bankAccounts;
}

class PersonAddress {
    Integer id;
    Integer personId;
    City city;
    Country country;
}
```

With PersonAddress it is fine. It does not have any sense without linking to city and country tables.

Problem comes when it goes to implement DAO for entities that are associated with Person, but not directly. These entities could exists without it. For example:

```
class User {
Integer id;
String username;
Date registeredOn;
... some other fields
Person person;
}

class Vehicle {
Integer id;
Person vehicleOwner;
VehicleBrand brand;
VehicleType type;
}
```

So, everytime I want to implement DAO methods:

- getVehicleById,
- getVehiclesByBrand,
- getUserById
- etc

I have to fetch information about `Person`, all `Addreses` and `BankAccounts` (and they are 1..n, so multiple rows must be fetched, and stored in a map)

I considered some solutions, but they feels like some workarounds rather than real answers to my problem:

- Make two methods in `UserDAO`, `VehicleDAO`: one that will fetch full entites, and second one, that will fetch only basic information about `Person` (without `Addreses` and `BankAccounts`).
  *Using this solution is not elegant, because it will not be certain if Person does not have any addreses or they just hadn't be fetched.*
- Make two `Person` models: `Person`, `PersonWithAddress`. *This however will in future lead to complete mess and funny names like `PersonWithXyzButWithoutYvz` or `VehicleWithPersonWithAddress`*
- In VehicleDAO fetch information only directly associated with Vehicle. 
  Rest objects fetch using PersonDAO if needed. *When all information will be needed this will cause 1+n selects (1 for list of vehicles, n for all vehicle owners)*

As I read, the DAO layer should be completely inaware of view. In the view I present information about Vehicle and only First and Last name of the owner. Fetching all information at this point is unnecessary. But between DAO and View there are other layers (Services) that *could* need that data.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Have you considered using something similar to Hibernate lazy loading.

Comment: You basically need to choose between implementing your own object-relational mapper or using a ready solution (e.g. Hibernate). This is a good example why writing your own solution is not trivial, even if your data model is relatively simple.